# Suite CRM - Label missing in subpanel

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have added a new field in the contacts subpanel of Accounts. The added field's name is coming in the Admin ->Studio->Accounts->labels. But it is not coming in the subpanel contacts lists. If i added another label also, it is coming in the Labels list of accounts in studio. Where i missed. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the label to the contacts module. As the sub panels are relationships to other modules. In this case the contacts module.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Let me try it once.